# How to split a string every nth character on VBA, unless nth character = " "?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string similar to

```
 "1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999"
```

Is it possible to split the string after each 10th character, without splitting the sub-strings (by subtrings I mean the "1111", "3333" etc),

```
1111
2222222 
3333 77777 
44444 
55555 6666
99999
```

I have tried this, but it's not quite right. Thanks

```
Dim i As Long, n As Long
Dim SplitStr, check_10th, TestStr As String
Dim string_length As Double

TestStr = Cells(1, 1)
n = 10

For i = 1 To Len(TestStr) Step n
    check_10th = Mid(TestStr, n, 1)
    If check_10th <> " " Then
        For k = 1 To 10 
            check_10th = Mid(TestStr, n - k, 1)
        If check_10th = " " Then
            Exit For
        End If

    Next k

    SplitStr = SplitStr & Mid(TestStr, i, n - k) & vbNewLine
Else
    SplitStr = SplitStr & Mid(TestStr, i, n) & vbNewLine
End If

Next i

Cells(2, 1).Value = SplitStr
```

Comment: What do you mean by *substrings* here?

Comment: if check_10th = " " then i = i+1... it would be better to use a do until loop for that scenario

Comment: T.M. By substrings, i mean the "1111" and "2222222", etc... Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean with substring `3333 77777`. Did you mean to split these? Or are they somehow connected so they shouldn't be split? What is the logic behind this?

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: What does not make sense is why is `3333 77777` not split? but `44444` is split? Why is `44444` not grouped with `55555`, but `55555` is grouped with `6666`? It's very hard to see the pattern you are after.

Comment: The 3333 77777 is not split as it is 10 characters, the 44444 combined with the 55555 is 11 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would be a lot better off here splitting your string into an array and testing from there.

Something like this (totally not optimized, but it works fine):

```
Sub test()
    Dim somestring As String
    Dim word As Variant
    Dim outline As String
    Dim outstring As String

    somestring = "1111 2222222 3333 77777 44444 55555 6666 99999"

    For Each word In Split(somestring, " ")
        If Len(outline & " " & word) <= 10 Then
            outline = Trim(outline & " " & word)
        Else
            If outstring = "" Then outstring = outline Else outstring = outstring & vbCrLf & Trim(outline)
            outline = word
        End If
    Next

    outstring = outstring & vbCrLf & Trim(outline)

    Debug.Print outstring
End Sub
```

Outputs:

```
1111
2222222
3333 77777
44444
55555 6666
99999
```

Comment: Split is the way to go.  But it is a much more interesting function that demonstrated above.  Split can return a two item array the first item of which is the first substring and the second part is the remainder substring.  Its well worth reading the MS help page on split.